# magento2.3.7 isDefault.checked(false); is not funcation

Tags: magento2.3.7

```
if (self.availableTypes.indexOf(optionType) != -1) {
                                if (self.checked() == true) {
                                    option.elems.each(function (record) {
                                        var isDefault = record._elems[self.isDefaultIndex];
                                        if (isDefault != self) {
                                            console.log("test225");
                                            //isDefault.checked(false);
                                            isDefault.checked(false);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

most probably isDefault is null

replace `if (isDefault != self) {` with `if (isDefault && isDefault != self) {`